# Display every keyboard character pressed Python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When I watched ecnerwala videos on competitive programming, I found something interesting in his video.

This running text
[ecnerwala running text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHENk.png)

Here is the link of the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ExmrrXi04vI&t=1030s

So I tried to create something like that running text using tkinter.text widget in python.
I create a window, add text object to it, and bind all keyboard keys to the window. I insert those keys into the text object when any key is pressed. I also make sure that even if I press the enter button, I don't insert it as a newline to the text widget but as the word 'Return' instead

Of course, there is a possibility that the length of all characters I insert into the text is longer than the length of the text widget could fit in one sentence. That's why I want to make the text widget to "always" see the characters from index END-(the number of character the widget could fit) until END

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *

def handle(event):
    text.config(state = NORMAL)
    text.insert(END, event.keysym)
    text.config(state = DISABLED)

    # Things to be fix
    text.doSomethingToMakeItBehaveLikeEntryWidget()

window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')

text = Text(window, font = ('Arial', 20), height = 1)
entry = Entry(window, font = ('Arial', 20))

text.config(state = DISABLED)

text.pack()
entry.pack()

window.bind('<Key>', handle)

window.mainloop()
```

Is there any solution for this problem? Even if I have to use another widget instead of text widget to solve it? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you use only one line in the text widget, you can use an entry in read-only mode instead.

No matter whether you use an entry or a text widget, you can use the method `text.xview_moveto(<fraction>)` to set which part of the content is visible, `<fraction>` being the relative portion of the widget's content which is hidden on the left. If you set this  fraction to 1, it will ensure that the last character is visible.

```
from tkinter import *

def handle(event):
    text.config(state=NORMAL)
    text.insert(END, event.keysym)
    text.config(state="readonly")
    text.xview_moveto(1)


window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')

text = Entry(window, font = ('Arial', 20), state="readonly", readonlybackground="white")
entry = Entry(window, font = ('Arial', 20))

text.config(state = DISABLED)

text.pack()
entry.pack()

window.bind('<Key>', handle)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

def handle(event):
    text.config(state = NORMAL)
    text.insert(END, event.keysym)
    text.config(state = DISABLED)
    t = text.get('1.0','end-1c')
    length= len(t)
    width =text.winfo_width()
    max_char = int((35/500)*width)
    if max_char < length:
        a = length-max_char
        text.config(state = NORMAL)
        text.delete(1.0,END)
        text.insert(1.0,t[a:])
        text.config(state = DISABLED)

window = Tk()
window.geometry('500x500')

text = Text(window, font = ('Arial', 20), height = 1)
entry = Entry(window, font = ('Arial', 20))

text.config(state = DISABLED)

text.pack()
entry.pack()

window.bind('<Key>', handle)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you add some explanations about your solution?

Comment: Could you explain why max_char = int((35/500)*width)? Where did 35 and 500 come from?

Comment: @HahahaHihihi This is the relation between the char and the width of the text widget. When the width of the Text widget is 500, you can insert 34 or 35 char in it.